# Is there an official spec defining the "Nandroid" backup format? If not, what was the first-ever tool which could create such backups?

Tags: android, backup, history

## Background

If you want to write a tool which can back up an Android device, you must choose a format in which to store the backups.  You can roll your own format, or you can conform to a pre-existing standard.

If you choose to conform to a pre-existing standard, there are various common backup formats you can choose from.  Nowadays, the "Nandroid" backup format is one common choice, and there are quite a few tools which can create such backups.  One of our sister sites, Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange, has a ["nandroid" tag wiki](//android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info) which can tell you more about this backup format.

## My question

I wonder:

- Is there an official specification which defines the "Nandroid" backup format?
- If not:

  - What was the first-ever tool which was able to create "Nandroid" backups?
  - Who wrote the tool?  Please tell me either their real name or their "pen name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any official spec which defines the Nandroid backup format.  (That doesn't mean there isn't one; it just means I don't know of one.)

But I think I know what the first-ever Nandroid backup tool was.

I've tried a Google advanced search, restricted by date.  I've also tried an XDA advanced search of certain forums, with results sorted by date.  I found [version 2.0 of a standalone Nandroid backup tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830).  Version 2.0 of the tool was released way back in December '08.  Post #1 in that thread talks about the tool and how to make a backup.  Post #2 provides detailed step-by-step instructions on how to do a restore.

Post #2 says:

> I am going to assume you already have a Nandroid backup created on your SD card using JF 1.31's recovery Alt-B feature.

Wait.  So was JesusFreke's custom recovery image also able to create Nandroid backups?

No.  Some [release notes](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=466174) for a release of JesusFreke's recovery image state:

> The coolest new functionality in v1.3 is a new backup utility that allows you to perform a backup directly from recovery mode with alt+B. This is done using infernix's and brainaid's nandroid script, which they kindly modified to work in recovery mode. Let them know what you think :) .

In addition, Infernix's [XDA signature](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=637772) says:

> Author of the original [nandroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830) & member of TeamApexQ.

And so it seems to me that Infernix almost surely wrote the first-ever Nandroid tool.